# Where am I now? #1

Tags: riddle

> I am standing in front of this sculpture
>   Of a creature
>   In the middle of this busy square
>   Full of people everywhere
>   If only it had a name
>   I looked at the maker and I thought to myself
>   I know him, I’ve heard of him painting many shores

Where am I now?

Hint 1:

> I am in Europe

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Trafalgar Square?

I'm standing in front of this sculpture of a creature:

> There are sculptures of lions in Trafalgar Square

In the middle of a busy square full of people everywhere:

> There are about 7 million annual visits to Trafalgar Square

If only it had a name:

> No clue?!?

I looked at the maker and I thought to myself I know him, I’ve heard of him painting many shores:

> Niel Nelson is a painter who has done many sea and beach scenes. Nelson's column is in Trafalgar Square.

Comment: It is in Trafalgar Square, but not the square itself. Hint rot13(qba'g gnxr nyy gur jbeqf va gur evqqyr nf gurl frrz) Good try +1

Comment: Need another hint?

Comment: @Daniil Yes please

Comment: rot13(znar naq fuberf ner nantenzf)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a

> Magic Square? See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square

I am standing in front of this sculpture:

> The Passion façade of the Sagrada Família church in Barcelona, conceptualized by Antoni Gaudí and designed by sculptor Josep Subirachs, features a 4×4 magic square

Of a creature:

> Magic squares of order 3 through 9, assigned to the seven planets, and described as means to attract the influence of planets and their angels (or demons) during magical practices, can be found in several manuscripts all around Europe starting at least since the 15th century.

In the middle of this busy square

> Busy square refers to the term "magic square" which is "busy" because the concept is redeployed in countless mathematical, literary, and artistic contexts.

Full of people everywhere:

> The Kubera-Kolam, a magic square of order three, is commonly painted on floors in India. (Hence, full of people everywhere).

If only it had a name:

> Depending on further properties, magic squares are also classified as associative magic squares, pandiagonal magic squares, most-perfect magic squares, and so on. More challengingly, attempts have also been made to classify all the magic squares of a given order as transformations of a smaller set of squares. Except for n ≤ 5, the enumeration of higher order magic squares is still an open challenge.

I looked at the maker and I thought to myself I know him, I’ve heard of him painting many shores

> The first recorded account of a Magic Square was the "Luo Shu magic square." Legends dating from as early as 650 BCE tell the story of the Lo Shu (洛书) or "scroll of the river Lo" (hence shore). The actual legend speaks of a painting of a map of the Yellow River.  Another possibility is that the famous order four magic square Albrecht Dürer immortalized in his 1514 engraving Melencolia I.  Albrecht Dürer had a number of famous watercolor paintings (shore) and was one of Europe's first landscape painters.

Comment: +1 for creativity but not one I was looking for